# Google OAuth no longer supported for progressive applications?

Tags: ios, oauth, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps

I have a progressive app (as defined in https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and it just started getting `disallowed_useragent` when initiating google OAuth flow

I found this notice https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

It seems that progressive apps should not have been disallowed from the flow.

Progressive apps are not an embedded webview, it's the same web page and regular browser without controls. There is no native layer and I cannot use the native SDK's

What is the new recommended approach for progressive web apps?

Comment: have just hit this issue happening with oAuth from a native iOS app in the past day too

Comment: You are correct, the intent is not to interfere with progressive web app behavior. Can you provide a link to your PWA so we can take a look at it?

Comment: @StevenSoneff same case here with our PWA. I could give you a link to try, but you would need to create a user, etc. Let me know if we can provide you with any additional details

Comment: I'm using iOS Safari, when I use the app in any tab, the OAuth flows without problem opening a new tab and closing it after the login.  But if i add the pago to Home Screen (full screen web app) the oauth process is broken and I'm receiving since yesterday the ugly 403 Error: disallowed_usergagent.  It's there any way to avoid this?  This is not a webview, is a safari link added to Home Screen!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the details, yes, I see, we can reproduce this with the Add to Home Screen functionality. Unfortunately this home screen version doesn't share the cookie state with the system Safari browser and has a webview user agent, and does not show the address bar, so it's indistinguishable from a webview. We're looking in to any way to support this (Note that Add to Home Screen on Android Chrome etc is not affected because it shares cookie state, behaves like full Chrome, and shows the address bar for Google Sign-In, avoiding the underlying problems associated with authenticating in webview)

Comment: @StevenSoneff So what is the solution then? We are not using a webview and we cannot use a native sdk... So our apps are all just broken now?

Comment: Hi, it seems that is not the problems with GG auth because now I am getting the same issue on IOS when adding to home screen.

Comment: Hi @Steven, another friendly reminder about this topic. Are you guys planning to deploy any change that we can test at any time? Any  advice on a workaround for iOS standalone solutions? Thanks!

Comment: @Steven I can log in again to my app, did you guys change something or is it iOS11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long story short it works again - has been for few weeks now

I could not find specific release notes, and i'm not sure if problem was fixed on apple or google side, please share if you know - I'm curious if it's a permanent solution

Answer (score -1):

The recommended approach is to use the device's system browser or the native SDK.

If you are a Cordova user, use this. It works for me. It is a nice replacement to the InAppBrowser: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Comment: This is for PWA's - which are just normal websites. Native SDK's and Cordova is not a solution.